# Output function ('&') in AngularJS .component() not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angular 1.5.6 component. I am trying to use the output binding ('&') but impossible to get it work. I have [plunkered](http://plnkr.co/edit/CJ70GPSoQ1WT0jiVkVPr) my issue.

Code for index.html :

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
  <my-view></my-view>
</body>
```

Code for the component for which I want to use output binding :

```
app.component('myInput', {
  template: [
    '<div class="form-group">',
    '<label>{{$ctrl.label}}</label>',
    '<input placeholder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.fieldValue"/>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''),
  controller: function() {},
  bindings: {
    label: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    fieldValue: '=',
    onUpdate: '&'
  }
});
```

Code for the parent component (output binding is done with the attribute on-update):

```
app.component('myView', {
  template: [
    '<div class="container">',
    '    <h2>My form with component</h2>',
    '    <form role="form">',
    '      <my-input on-update="$ctrl.updateParam()" label="Firstname" placeholder="Enter first name" field-value=$ctrl.intermediaryData.firstName ></my-input>',
    '    </form>'
  ].join(''),
  controller: function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.userData = {
      firstName: 'Xavier',
      lastName: 'Dupont',
      age: 25
    };

    ctrl.intermediaryData = {
      firstName: ctrl.userData.firstName,
      lastName: ctrl.userData.lastName,
      age: 25
    };

    function updateParam(){
      console.log("I have updated the component");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: what doesn't work? It doesn't look like you are using `onUpdate` anywhere

Comment: In the component my-view see : `on-update="$ctrl.updateParam()"` this is supposed to call function updateParam()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My bad, I have forgotten to put ng-change in input component. I managed to solve the issue like this :

```
app.component('myInput', {
  template: [
    '<div class="form-group">',
    '<label>{{$ctrl.label}}</label>',
    '<input ng-change="$ctrl.change()" placeholder="{{$ctrl.placeholder}}" class="form-control" ng-model="$ctrl.fieldValue"/>',
    '</div>'
  ].join(''),
  controller: function() {
    var ctrl = this;

    ctrl.change = function(){
      ctrl.onUpdate();
    }
  },
  bindings: {
    label: '@',
    placeholder: '@',
    parentParam: '@',
    fieldValue: '=',
    onUpdate: '&'
  }
});
```